# Copying a linked list node and inserting it in the middle of a linked list

Tags: java, list, methods, linked-list

I'm writing a method called twin() that would take a linked list [1 2 3 4] and return [1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4]. I have a working method but I'm confused about a part. In my code, i declare a new SListNode variable called temp. I want this temp to copy the current node and then connect it. When I try to do SListNode temp = current, the program won't run. However, if I manually set temp's item and next fields, the method will run just fine. Can anyone explain what happens when you do SListNode temp = current please?

```
public void twin() {

    SListNode current = head;
    if(current == null){
        return;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i <this.length();i++){
        if(current == null){
            return;
        }
        SListNode temp = new SListNode(0); // Problem here when I substitute these 3 lines for SListNode temp = current;
        temp.next = current.next; 
        temp.item = current.item;
        current.next = temp;
        current = current.next.next;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"the program won't run"*. What error are you getting?

Comment: Is it a circular list? how is the length() computed?

Comment: Notice that when you do `temp = current`, you are not copying the object. You are just giving another way to access to that object. In other words, `temp` and `current` will *refer* to the same object.

Answer (score 0):

If you did `temp = current`, you won't copying the object. You will be just giving another way to access to that object. In other words, `temp` and `current` will be *referring* to the same object.

If you did that, the lines

```
temp.next = current.next; 
temp.item = current.item;
```

won't do anything, because it will be like doing `temp.next = temp.next`.

Also, in the line

```
current.next = temp;
```

you would be making `current`'s next *node* to be itself (`current.next` will be `current`).